# Jenkins ec2 plugin - windows agent is very slow

Tags: windows, jenkins, networking, amazon-ec2, winrm

`enter code here`I'm trying to use jenkins ec2 plugin and I have problems with performance.
My options for winrm:

```
winrm set winrm/config/service/Auth @{Basic="true"}
winrm set winrm/config/service @{AllowUnencrypted="true"}
winrm set winrm/config/winrs @{MaxMemoryPerShellMB="1024"}
```

Jenkins 2.133
OS Windows 2016r2
Java 8 x64

My next steps took a lot of time:

```
11:47:48 Building remotely on zak-test (sir-4pcr5aig) (zak-test) in workspace c:\jenkins\workspace\AT_PES_test_zak
11:58:48 Cloning the remote Git repository
```

next step

```
12:07:52 Parsing POMs
12:39:51 Established TCP socket on 49811
```

When I use JNLP protocol instead WinRm my tests are work without these pauses. Quickly.

Moreover, I created task
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-53617
but i didn't receive response.

then, I use local windows user jenkins for connect from master to windows agent ec2 instance. I launched gui tests by google chrome. When tests is working I'm connecting via RDP to my agent windows host and I'm watching that chrome is working in background. But I didn't see my browser as GUI process. Only in powershell:

```
 PS C:\Users\jenkins> get-process

Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K)     CPU(s)     Id  SI ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      -----     ------     --  -- -----------
    181      10    46960      15820              1512   0 amazon-ssm-agent
    123      10     1784       8624               740   0 chrome
    251      20    18392      30260       0.11   2228   0 chrome
    246      20    18388      30584       0.13   3276   0 chrome
   1008      55    21552      72832              3444   0 chrome
    154      10     1860       7884              4600   0 chrome
    403      21    15368      23840       0.19   5840   0 chrome
    226      20     6680      12320              1396   0 chromedriver
```

Answer (score 0):

WinRM is slowly protocol. Despite this plugin is very comfortable for using Linux instances.

Answer (score 0):

I had also this issue, like @ZakShirak says, WinRM is really slow and not so good.

I resolved this issue by connecting and configure the windows instances to run as Linux ssh instance. (in the ec2-plugin configuration)

1. added openssh server to the Windows ami with a preconfigured keys.
2. and edit the jenkins start command prefix (because it is writing something like this:  java  -jar C:\jenkins\/remoting.jar -workDir C:\jenkins)

I edit the prefix command to: "java -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\temp -jar C:\jenkins\remoting.jar -workDir C:\jenkins  &rem"
(with the &rem that, so everything that the plugin insert to the command is ignored)